# add google maps marker using click

Tags: firefox, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

Ok so I am trying to add a marker when I click on it, but the code on google's documentation is not working. I am using coffeescript and running it in Firefox.

```
#onload event listener for the map

google.maps.event.addDomListener window,'load', ->

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-here'), mapOptions)
  marker = new google.maps.Marker {position:defPosition,map:map,title:'hi', }
  google.maps.event.addListener map, 'click', (event) ->
  placeMarker event.latLng
  return
#end

placeMarker = (location) ->
  marker = new (google.maps.Marker)(
  position: location
  map: map)
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong indentation. Try

```
google.maps.event.addListener map, 'click', (event) ->
  placeMarker event.latLng
```

instead of

```
google.maps.event.addListener map, 'click', (event) ->
placeMarker event.latLng
```